# Use wifi instead of LAN for some apps

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, proxy, lan

At work I need to be connected to the LAN with a proxy. This proxy blocks a lot of things that I still want to access, one of them being Spotify.

We also have a wifi which works just fine, but as mentioned, I need to be on the proxy via LAN.

My question: Can I selectively tell apps to use wifi instead of my LAN connection?